# Prompt users that ask lots of questions but don’t up vote match to up vote more

Tags: feature-request

Can something be done to get users like this to vote more?  E.g.

Show them a message when they ask a question pointing out that they have not voted match on answers to other questions.

Sending them a friendly email from a modulator and/or show them the message when ever they use the site until they have dismissed it.

Show a “poor up voter”  label on all questions they post.

I think people should be up voting at **least** trice the number of times they ask questions.  Only people will a VERY poor upvoting record should be targeted

Comment: You make it sound as if people who don't vote are a **problem** but provide no reasoning behind that.

Comment: @TheTXI: You're just repeating what I said in the other thread. Learn to come up with your own arguments, you sycophant.

Comment: Why aren't you upvoting these great answers to your question?

Comment: My, that's a big laser you have, Susan!

Comment: @WelbogLaserSusasnCanadianSamsonGuy: You are my inspiration in life.

Comment: @TheTXI: Your life is pitiable.

Comment: I think Susan's compensating for something with that big laser.

Comment: @Jon B: You're right. I'm compensating for the fact that the world has a woefully inadequate supply of sufficiently large lasers. If I were to personify the world's quantity of large lasers, I would end up with a pitiful being not unlike TheTXI in its poverty and inability to cope with reality. And so I must build my own big laser, and point it at extraterrestrial objects that have done me no wrong but whose fates I hold in my hand via remote big laser control. I hope you didn't grow too attached to Ceres or 99942 Apophis, because they're next on my list of things to shoot with a big laser.

Comment: Not 99942 Apophis! Nooooooooooooo!

Comment: I have laserred the solar system. Pray I do not laser it any further.

Comment: I hope the *modulators* are paying attention.

Comment: @pavium: On a topic completely unrelated to your terrible pun and my big laser, what is your precise geographic location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already being done with the **acceptance rate**; it's enough to get attention to the fact they don't accept answers, there's no need to stone and shame them for having poor acceptance rates.

And they also get messages asking them to start a bounty if they don't have a good enough answer. The truth is, whatever you do, if they don't want to mark an answer as accepted, there's nothing anybody can do. Just answer the question if you can and let others judge if your answer is good enough.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like it when the system tries to go out of its way to tell me how to cast MY votes. I will vote how and why I choose and as long as I do not do so in an abusive manner it should not make any difference whether I ask 100 questions and cast 1000 upvotes or ask 1000 questions and cast only 10 upvotes.

Upvotes and downvotes are not something that you are obligated to cast, and to be quite honest we probably have people who already cast **too many** upvotes and **not enough** downvotes to where it skews everybody's perception of the site into something more akin to "Yay! You made an effort! Here's a backpat and a gold star!"

Comment: Better not spend time on some SE sites out there. It's a veritable hippie fest of upvote only love.

Comment: I think I went on meta.stackexchange one time when it was first created and also the travel one. The color schemes scared me off and now I refuse to go back.